# Javascript, FireFox и DOCTYPE html PUBLIC

Tags: javascript, firefox, doctype

Подскажите пожалуйста от чего может не работать javascript в Firefox если присутствует обязательный на мой взгляд

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Скрипт таков, и характерно что очень простой

```
function myFunc(elem1, elem2, elem3)
{
    elem1.style.display = 'block';
    elem2.style.display = 'none';
    elem3.style.display = 'none';   
}
```

вызывается следующим образом

```
onclick = "myFunc(e1, e2, e3);"
```

Что ему нужно XD)

Воложил код...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunc(elem1, elem2, elem3)
{
    elem1.style.display = 'block';
    elem2.style.display = 'none';
    elem3.style.display = 'none';   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="e3">Previous</div>
<input onclick="myFunc(e1, e2, e3)" type="submit" id="send" value="getE1" />
<input onclick="myFunc(e2, e1, e3)" type="submit" id="send" value="getE2" />
<div id="e1" style="display:none;">e1</div>
<div id="e2" style="display:none;">e2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: onclick, я так понимаю, вы так в самом теле страницы пишите?О_о<br>
Если да то возникает вопрос - чему равны в данном случае e1,e2,e3 как думаете? ^^<br>
PS:причем тут DOCTYPE то?<br>
PPS:если я вас не правильно понял - выложите пожалуйста весь код...

Comment: если убрать строку DOCTYPE то все ок!
e1,e2,e3 равны id
как в теле страницы писать onclick еще? так утроит? onclick="myFunc(e1, e2, e3);"
Скрипт преведен для примера а не для выяснения мелочей!

Comment: Вы код номральновыложить весь можете или нет? <br>Если бы это была бы мелочь я бы не спрашивал, вам это в голову не приходило? Просто пост из разряда - вот у меня есть код и там такая вот ошибка, коди дето примерно такой, в чем дело ^^
<small>[offtop]ну вас каша в голове...[/offtop]</small>

Comment: Если использовать DOCTYPE таким
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

То все нормально! Вот и интересно почему вот так вот выходит все!

Comment: Почему это работает я вообще бесспонятия, суть в том что код нелогичен и ужасен... собственно начинайте уже юзать firebug, многие вопросы отпадут сами собой, коди приведенный ниже работает с любым doctype...

Comment: Мне DragonFly больше по душе) Чпасибо за приведенный рабочий пример!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну во первых передаем мы строку а не переменную, т.е. нужно напистаь не `myFunc(e2, e1, e3)`, а `myFunc('e2', 'e1', 'e3')`, надеюсь это понятно...
ну и вообще:

```
function myFunc(elem1, elem2, elem3)
{
    //сначало выберем еллементы, не?..
    elem1 = document.getElementById(elem1);
    elem2 = document.getElementById(elem2);
    elem3 = document.getElementById(elem3);

    //ну а теперь уже мы можем играться со стилями...
    elem1.style.display = 'block';
    elem2.style.display = 'none';
    elem3.style.display = 'none';   
}
```

Теперь надеюсь ясно что doctype тут не причем? :)

Comment: Принято! Но суть вопроса была в том почему именно в FF не работает! Приведенный мною пример IE6 хавает)